# How can I export a rigged and posed model from Blender to Substance painter without losing the pose?

Tags: armature, export, external-applications

I want to render it in Substance because Blender's HDRI based lighting doesn't work well with my model.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Armature modifier in the stack before exporting. Alternatively you can tick the "Apply Modifiers" export setting.